# Expected value of Uniform distribution

Tags: expected-value, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X$ is an uniform random variable: $X \sim U(a,b)$.

I know how to compute $E(X)$, but what if I want to compute: $E(X^\gamma)$ where $\gamma > 0$?

Comment: If $\gamma$ is integer, you may directly use the mgf, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)

Comment: If this is a home work, you need to show your work, what have you done so far.

Comment: The moment generating function should do the trick. 
If my interpretation is correct, would the answer be:
$E(X^\gamma) = \frac{1}{\gamma+1} \sum_{i=0}^\gamma a^i b^{\gamma-i}$?

Answer (score 1):

By [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), if $f_X (x) = \frac{1}{b-a}$ and $g(X) = x^\gamma$,

$\mathbb{E}[g(X)]= \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f(x)\,dx = \frac {1}{b-a}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^\gamma \,dx = \frac {1}{b-a}\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b} x^\gamma \,dx$.

Comment: And since $\gamma > 0$, this would solve to $(b^{\gamma+1} - a^{\gamma+1})/((\gamma+1)(b-a))$.

Comment: @Greenparker, Antoni stopped short of a full answer because this is obviously a [tag:self-study] question.  Please follow [the link to the tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) to read about our site policy concerning how such questions are answered.